# made a form with java and storing its values in database but it has some database query error?

Tags: java, html

#this is when i didn't feed any values

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values('','','','','',null,'','',''))' at line 1

#this is when i enter the values
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values('**********785@gmail.com','','Aashin','sood','vpo bhawarn teh palampur di' at line 1

#and this is my code
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet{

```
private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO  USER (email, password, firstname, lastname, address, pincode, state,  number, feedback values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))";
```

i dont know if the reason of error is this or something else

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You omitted a closing bracket before **values**

update your code to
'''private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO  USER (email, password, firstname, lastname, address, pincode, state,  number, feedback) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";'''

Comment: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'number' at row 1

Comment: now this is the new error i think the last one is solved

Comment: @AashinSood the data you are trying to insert doesn't fit. Consider expanding the size of the datatype in your column